# How can I remove Unity icons that launch nothing?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, shortcuts

I have a problem involving shortcuts in the dash. When I click one, it launches nothing. How can I remove these useless shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the offending shortcut. Choose Unlock from launcher.

Comment: what i meant was, deleting shortcuts from your applications menu, not from the bar on the left.

Comment: @forgecrafter I misunderstood your use of the word Dash. I suggest you edit your question to provide as much information as possible in order to help us help you! Thanks!